# Reading files from folder and appending it to xlsx file

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have a folder that have say a few hundreds files and is growing every hour. I am trying to consolidate all the data into a single file for analysis use. But the script I wrote is not too effective for processing these data as it will read all the content in the folder and append it to an xlsx file. The processing time is simply too long.
What I seeking is to enhance and improve  my script:
1) To be able to only read and extract data new files that have not been previously read 
2) To extract and append these data to update the xlxs file.

I just need some to enlightenment to help me improve on the script.

Part of my code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os 
import dask.dataframe as dd
import glob
import schedule
import time 
import re
import datetime as dt


def job():
    # Select the path to download the files 
    path=r'V:\DB\ABCD\BEFORE\8_INCHES'
    files=glob.glob(path+"/*.csv")

    df=None
    # Extracting of information from files 
    for i, file in enumerate (files) :
        if i==0:
             df= np.transpose(pd.read_csv(file,delimiter="|",index_col=False))
             df['Path'] =file
             df['Machine No']=re.findall("MC-11",str(df["Path"]))
             df['Process']= re.findall("ABCD",str(df["Path"]))
             df['Before/After']=re.findall("BEFORE",str(df["Path"]))
             df['Wafer Size']=re.findall("8_INCHES",str(df["Path"]))
             df['Employee ID']=df["Path"].str.extract(r'(?<!\d)(\d{6})(?!\d)',expand=False)
             df['Date']=df["Path"].str.extract(r'(\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})',expand=False)
             df['Lot Number']=df["Path"].str.extract(r'(\d{7}\D\d)',expand=False)
             df['Part Number']=df["Path"].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2,3}\d{3,4}[A-Z][A-Z]\d{2,4}[A-Z])',expand=False)
             df["Part Number"].fillna("ENGINNERING SAMPLE",inplace=True)
        else:
            tmp= np.transpose(pd.read_csv(file,delimiter="|",index_col=False))
            tmp['Path'] =file
            tmp['Machine No']=tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'(\D{3}\d{2})',expand=False)
            tmp['Process']=  tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'(\w{8})',expand=False)
            tmp['Before/After']= tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'([B][E][F][O][R][E])',expand= False)
            tmp['Wafer Size']= tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'(\d\_\D{6})',expand= False)
            tmp['Employee ID']=tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'(?<!\d)(\d{6})(?!\d)',expand=False)
            tmp['Date']=tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'(\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})',expand=False)
            tmp['Lot Number']=tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'(\d{7}\D\d)',expand=False)
            tmp['Part Number']=tmp["Path"].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2,3}\d{3,4}[A-Z][A-Z]\d{2,4}[A-Z])',expand=False)
            tmp["Part Number"].fillna("ENGINNERING SAMPLE",inplace=True)

            df= df.append(tmp)



        export_excel= rf.to_excel(r'C:\Users\hoosk\Documents\Python Scripts\hoosk\test26_feb_2020.xlsx')




#schedule to run every hour 
schedule.every(1).hour.do(job)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you use a different file format? We know nothing about the relevant data, so I'm not sure how much anyone can do.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms you'll want to do the following:

1. Read in the xlsx file at the start of your script.
2. Extract a set with all the filename already parsed (Path attribute)
3. For each file you iterate over check if it is contained within the set of already processed files.

This assumes that existing files don't have their content updated. If that could happen, you may want to track metrics like last change date (a checksum would be most reliable, but probably too expensive to compute).